# jQuery ajax and append - content too large?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am writing an ajax search page that contains a search box and "tabs"; the idea is that a user enters a query, changes the tab, the query is submitted with new options, and results loaded below.

I am having a weird issue where the length(?) of the data ('content') returned seems to stop me running any extra JS.

See below, #resultsArea is designed to have several sets of results in it as a user flicks between tabs so it'll show cached results if the query is the same rather than sending another unnecessary db query.

"Content" is the data returned - and it seems as soon as I use this (whether it be in an alert, or printed on the page), I cannot execute any more javascript. If I remove +content+ from the .append function, the alert following the line will fire. Is this by design?

"Content" contains quite a large quantity of data - loads of  s and formatting, so I wonder if this is the issue. However this all works and displays OK as it is! I just want to add some extra JS so I can load adverts into the rendered results, but this is stumping me.

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: formUrl,
data: formData,
dataType: 'html',
success: function(content) {
    $('#resultsBit').slideUp(200);

    if (query!=prevQuery)
        {   
            $('#results_'+flavour).remove();
        }

    alert('I will fire');

    $('#resultsArea').append('<div id="results_'+flavour+'" style="display:true;">'+content+'</div>');

    alert('I will not fire');

    }
});
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: If Stack Overflow is any indicator, copy-pasting code without ruining the indentation is super-hard. `:P`

Comment: Ha ha... my indents were definitely not preserved!

Comment: Are you getting timeout error?

Comment: If the content contains Javascript or anything that is breaking the append, this behavior is expected. What do you see in chrome inspector/firebug after the ajax post? Do you see any errors?

Comment: TJ - That was the problem, thanks! There was a stray reference to an undefined function... I'd noticed it before, but ignored it as I'm used to JS completely grinding to a halt at the slightest syntax error. The content rendering correctly threw me off. Thanks again!

Comment: How do I mark this Q as answered and TJ's post as the solution?

Answer (score 0):

> If I remove `+content+` from the `.append()` function, the alert following the line will fire. Is this by design?

This gives a pretty big clue as to what's going on; that means something inside `content` is causing an error (an exception is thrown actually) and this error can be seen from the console.

Without a console you could wrap your code inside a `try { } catch` block like this:

```
try {
    $('#resultsArea').append('<div id="results_'+flavour+'" style="display:true;">'+content+'</div>');
} catch (e) {
    alert('Oh no, error: ' + e);
}
```

That should give you a clue as to what's wrong with `content.`